# I need help partitioning arrays and Deques of Strings using the partition step of the Quicksort algorithm

Tags: java, arrays, string, quicksort, deque

So I have two methods that are receiving an array or Deque of strings, as well as a pivot string:

- > public static Deque partition(Deque, String) ;
- > public static String[] partition(String[], String) ;

And what I'm trying to figure out is how they will return a new array or Deque of Strings which contains the same Strings as the input but where the elements less than or equal to the pivot are stored at the beginning of the new array or Deque. It doesn't matter if the string appears more than once.

All the solutions I've found so far involve using integers, not strings, and I'm not sure how to adapt them to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

With the deque you first create a new empty deque, then add the strings <= the pivot to the front of the deque and those that are > the pivot to the back. With the String[] you are basically manually simulating the deque. You can do this by using a real deque and then converting to a string array at the end. Or you can first create the result string array and maintain two separate indices, one for the front and one for the back. The front one starts at 0 and the back one starts at result.length - 1. You should be able to figure out the rest on your own.

Comment: So I would have something like     private Deque<String>[] first ; and
    private String[] last ; what do I do with the two methods I've already been given. They give me an error saying missing method body and identifier expected.